# HBASE/MR - Map called despite filter, but no output

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

## Question

I would like to confirm the following:

> If a filter has filtered-out a row, the mapper should *not* be called with it.

## Goal

Trying to add a `meta:uuid` column to rows which don't have such column already.

Oddly, all seem to work, despite the logs suggesting otherwise.

## Code

Filter:

```
new SingleColumnValueFilter( 
    Bytes.toBytes( "meta" ), 
    Bytes.toBytes( "uuid" ), 
    CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL, 
    new NullComparator()
);
```

Map:

```
@Override
public void map( ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result columns, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Put put = new Put( row.get() );

    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    put.add( META_COLUMNFAMILY, UUID_QUALIFIER, uuid.getBytes() );


    System.out.println( uuid.toString() );
    context.write( row, put );
}
```

## Behaviour

### First run

It adds `meta:uuid` column to all rows.

### Second run

We still get the `System.out.println( uuid.toString() )` output with new UUIDs - this suggests that the mapper has been called.

But the UUIDs (or timestamp) do not change in HBASE.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as the [docs say](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html):

> You must also specify a family and qualifier. Only the value of this column will be tested. When using this filter on a CellScanner with specified inputs, the column to be tested should also be added as input (otherwise the filter will regard the column as missing).

So I had to add:

```
scan.addColumn( Bytes.toBytes( "meta" ), Bytes.toBytes( "uuid" ) );
```

(As for why the UUID didn't change - that seem to do with some issue with HBase that was rectified after restart.)